# Moderncv does not give PDF or any error

Tags: xetex, pdftex, moderncv, texniccenter, miktex-update

I use MiKTeX and TeXnicCenter on windows 7, I would to write my cv using `moderncv`  and compile it with `xelatex`.

I tried the following code in the accepted answer from this post [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289449/moderncv-does-not-compile/302319#302319)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv} % version 1.5.1

%\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}  % used in version <= 0.15
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\firstname{firstname}     % Your name
\lastname{Lastname}       % Your last name
\title{Title}             % Your title (optional)
\address{street and number}{post code and city}   % Your current address
\mobile{number}           % Your mobile phone number
\phone{number}            % Your phone number
\email{email}             % Your email address
\homepage{link}           % Your website
\extrainfo{information}   % Possible extra information e.g. website
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}             % Your photo (optional)
\quote{quote}             % Life motto or something like that (optional)

\setlength{\footskip}{52pt} % to avoid warning


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cvlanguage{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvcomputer{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
%\cvline{hobby 1}{\small Description} % cvline used in version <= 0.15
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

[image]

Anyone could help me solving this problem

```
    Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifluatex' (already loaded).
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: pdfTeX >= 1.30 not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen186
\Hy@linkcounter=\count196
\Hy@pagecounter=\count197

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count198

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg"
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4374.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\puenc.def"
File: puenc.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4498.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4503.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4506.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4513.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4518.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4751.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count199
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5104.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen187
\Fld@menulength=\count266
\Field@Width=\dimen188
\Fld@charsize=\dimen189
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6358.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6363.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6366.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6373.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6378.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6383.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6388.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6428.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6432.
\Hy@abspage=\count267
\c@Item=\count268
\c@Hfootnote=\count269
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hxetex.def"
File: hxetex.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for XeTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\stringenc.sty"
Package: stringenc 2016/05/16 v1.11 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
)
\pdfm@box=\box54
\c@Hy@AnnotLevel=\count270
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count271
\Fld@listcount=\count272
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count273

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package rerunfilecheck Info: Feature \pdfmdfivesum is not available
(rerunfilecheck)             (e.g. pdfTeX or LuaTeX with package `pdftexcmds').
(rerunfilecheck)             Therefore file contents cannot be checked efficiently
(rerunfilecheck)             and the loading of the package is aborted.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip79
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `breaklinks' set `true' on input line 22.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksopen' set `true' on input line 22.
 (Educ.aux)
\openout1 = `Educ.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 22.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of kerning.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\microtype\mt-cmr.cfg"
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (RS)
) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box55
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 22.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count274
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 22.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 22.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 22.
 (Educ.out) (Educ.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `Educ.out'.

\makecvheaddetailsbox=\box56
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+lmr on input line 24.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\ot1lmr.fd"
File: ot1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+lmm on input line 24.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\omllmm.fd"
File: omllmm.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 24.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\omslmsy.fd"
File: omslmsy.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMX+lmex on input line 24.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\omxlmex.fd"
File: omxlmex.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10> on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 24.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\microtype\mt-mvs.cfg"
File: mt-mvs.cfg 2006/07/05 v1.1 microtype config. file: Marvosym Euro (RS)
)
\makecvheadpicturebox=\box57
File: example-image-a.pdf Graphic file (type QTm)
 <use  "example-image-a.pdf" >
\makecvheaddetailswidth=\skip80
\makecvheadpicturewidth=\skip81
\makecvheadnamebox=\box58
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 24.
 [1

]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 30.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 30.
 (Educ.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 30.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 30.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 28009 strings out of 427834
 520645 string characters out of 3152469
 583579 words of memory out of 3000000
 31659 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 598386 words of font info for 60 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 69i,11n,58p,10358b,329s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Error 1 (driver return code) generating output;
file Educ.pdf may not be valid.
```

please check [educ.log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LveniR9fmRsdComeHQXWMYs1am3nUY8WQ8yJsz9o5vM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried running the commands manually? The output you show mention BibTeX and MakeIndex problems.

Comment: Please how can i do that

Comment: the error messages suggest you ran bibtex  without first running latex

Comment: show the `.log` file that you got.

Comment: the problem i got nothing even the .log to post it

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with this code. Are sure `moderncv` is installed?

Comment: yes of course you can check the second picture in my question by the way i remove miktex and i'm trying to install the new version in hope to solve that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing your given log file with mine it results in several packages not up to date on your system.

Therefore an update is needed. To avoid problems with not installed packages or fonts I suggested in chat to install the complete MiKTeX.

Now the given code compiles without errors (as it did on my current and complete MiKTeX 2.9).